# Unable to start Hive on Windows 10: Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, windows-10, authorization

I'm trying to install Hive on Windows 10.  When attempting to start Hive I receive the following error:

> Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

I'm using Derby as my backend for Hive.  Here is my hive-site.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
    <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>NONE</value>
    <description>
      Client authentication types.
        NONE: no authentication check
        LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
        KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
        CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider
                (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
    </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
    <value>True</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I first start networkServer:

```
d:\Hadoop-2.8.1\sbin>startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
Fri Feb 09 08:57:01 EST 2018 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri Feb 09 08:57:01 EST 2018 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.14.1.0 - (1808820) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

Then run start-all.cmd:

```
d:\Hadoop-2.8.1\sbin>start-all.cmd
```

Check NetworkServerControl:

```
d:\Hadoop-2.8.1\sbin>jps -m
12532 ResourceManager
7156 NetworkServerControl start -h 0.0.0.0
20504 Jps -m
27336 DataNode
22604 NodeManager
492 NameNode
```

Finally, I try to start Hive and that is when I receive the error:

```
d:\Hadoop-2.8.1\sbin>hive
```

I notice in the hive's bin directory there is no metastore_db created:

```
Directory of d:\Hadoop-2.8.1\hive2_1\bin

02/06/2018  01:48 PM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2018  01:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             1,261 beeline
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             2,553 beeline.cmd
02/06/2018  01:48 PM    <DIR>          ext
11/28/2016  04:35 PM             8,692 hive
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             1,584 hive-config.cmd
02/09/2018  08:20 AM             1,900 hive-config.sh
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             8,823 hive.cmd
11/28/2016  04:32 PM               885 hiveserver2
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             1,030 hplsql
11/28/2016  04:32 PM             2,278 hplsql.cmd
11/28/2016  04:32 PM               832 metatool
11/28/2016  04:32 PM               884 schematool
              11 File(s)         30,722 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  427,455,606,784 bytes free
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem as yours.

I use:
 **1. hadoop-2.7.6

 2. derby-10.12.1.1

 3. hive-2.1.0**

This is my hive-site.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
        <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
        <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
        <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>NONE</value>
        <description>
            Client authentication types.
              NONE: no authentication check
              LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
              KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
              CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
        <value>True</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
        <value>True</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

This is the steps that I have done:

1. Create a directory, let's say 'TestHive' in drive C

```
C:\TestHive
```

2. Run start-all.cmd

```
C:\Users\{YOUR_PC-NAME}\start-all
```

3. Switch to 'TestHive' directory

```
C:\Users\{YOUR_PC-NAME}\cd C:\TestHive
```

4. Start startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0 in 'TestHive' directory

```
C:\TestHive\startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
```

5. Check NetworkServerControl

```
C:\TestHive>jps -m  
11012 Jps -m  
6196 DataNode  
9284 NetworkServerControl start -h 0.0.0.0  
7544 NameNode  
10092 NodeManager  
316 ResourceManager
```

6. Start hive.cmd in 'TestHive' directory

```
C:\TestHive>hive
```

Finally, this the result I get:

```
C:\TestHive>hive  
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurati  
on: logging only errors to the console.  
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://  
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.  
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/hive-2.1.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!  
/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]  
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j  
-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]  
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.  

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]  
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.1.0)  
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 2.1.0)  
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ  
Beeline version 2.1.0 by Apache Hive  
hive>
```

This is the content of 'TestHive' directory:

```
Directory of C:\TestHive

10/05/2018  16:37    <DIR>          .
10/05/2018  16:37    <DIR>          ..
10/05/2018  16:37               757 derby.log
10/05/2018  16:37    <DIR>          metastore_db
               1 File(s)            757 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  22.890.254.336 bytes free
```

Note: I assume that you have set all the variables and paths correctly in Windows' Environment Variables and run cmd as Administrator

Hope this will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to change this line in the hive-site.xml, instead of using localhost:1527

```
jdbc:derby:,databaseName=$HIVE_HOME/metastore_db;create=true
```

Also added the following two properties in the hive-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
<value>c:/tmp/hive/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```